# SDK encounters challenges what content to present in between extensions and mobile SDKs

Tags: provider, metamask, coinbase-api

This is a common problem of finding the proper wallet in a browser. If there is sdk and extension both are present and in normal cases, as developers, we use sdk to connect our application to connect with out mobile wallet. If we use the same extension installed in a browser it shows nothing while initializing the provider.

In my case person used Coinbase Sdk and if they did not install the coinbase extension it would work properly as given image below.

[image]

It also works in proper initialization and all that.

[image]

---

But as soon as anyone installed the extension it showed nothing during initialization like below image you can see.

[image]

---

In normal cases developers used

`window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });`

to connect with Metamask or another default extension. In this case, it triggered both wallets as extensions.

[image]

---

**how can I make a provider call so that a particular wallet connection action works properly?**